# PHP Script ,php://input check for empty File

Tags: php, upload

Hello i need help with my PHP script.
The Upload function works great, but many files are empty.

*Can you help me please to check first IF file is empty or < 1 byte. and Ignore them.*

```
   <?php
    $vist_page     =   "post2.php";
    include "logger.php";
    file_put_contents("outputfile.txt".uniqid(), file_get_contents("php://input"));
    ?>
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be to use `strlen()` to check the length of the string, which could be done by replacing

```
file_put_contents("outputfile.txt".uniqid(), file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

with

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (strlen($content)) {
    file_put_contents("outputfile.txt".uniqid(), $content);
}
else {
    // Your error response here
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works great ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (filesize($filename) < 1) {
//ignore

} else {
//do stuff here

}
```

filesize returns the file size in bytes
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

this may be more effecient:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (filesize($filename) > 0) {
//do stuff here

}
```